# Why the variables inside function are not initialized?

Tags: tensorflow

Produced below is an excerpt from my code: 
[image]

And then I run this:
[image]

and I get this error despite the fact that I even tried  `tf.initialize_all_variables()`
[image]

Can I know, WHY THE VARIABLES INSIDE FUNCTION [linear_layer] ARE NOT INITIALIZED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly create the variable such as `out` to let tensorflow know which graph element is evaluated. In your original code, you haven't built the graph when you call `tf.global_variables_initializer()`. That's why `W` is not initialized.

```py
def linear_layer(input, units):
    W = tf.Variable(initial_value=glorot(shape=(input.get_shape().as_list()[1], units)), name="W")
    B = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(input.get_shape().as_list()[0], 1)), name="B")
    out = tf.matmul(input, W) + B
    return out

out = linear_layer(input=tf.constant([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.]]), units=10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(out))

# [[ 0.8285629   0.7860288   1.8736962   0.4321289  -0.9692887  -1.638855
#   -0.19338632  0.5580156  -0.13394058  1.6745124 ]
#  [ 1.9110355   1.2211521   3.2454844  -0.9029484  -2.0184612  -2.753471
#   -0.29346204  0.340119    0.04118478  2.893313  ]]
```